# How to exclude inherited object properties from mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to setup a mapping for an object that looks like this:

```
class TestObject
{
    public long TestID { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Object)]
    public Dictionary<long, List<DateTime>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I use the following mapping code (where Client is `IElasticClient`):

```
this.Client.Map<TestObject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes());
```

I get the following mapping result:

```
{
"mappings": {
  "testobject": {
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "comparer": {
            "type": "object"
          },
          "count": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "item": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "keys": {
            "properties": {
              "count": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "values": {
            "properties": {
              "count": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "testID": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This becomes a problem when I want to do a search like this:

```
{
    "query_string": {
        "query": "[2015-06-03T00:00:00.000 TO 2015-06-05T23:59:59.999]",
            "fields": [
                "items.*"
                ]
              }
            }
```

This causes exceptions, that I guess are because of all the fields in the items object are not of the same type. What is the proper mapping to searches of this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using the following mapping:

```
this.Client.Map<TestObject>(m => m.MapFromAttributes())
    .Properties(p => p
        .Object<Dictionary<long, List<DateTime>>>(o => o.Name("items")));
```